# JVM: How to manage off-heap memory created by JNI

Tags: java, scala, jvm, swig, torch

I'm building a Scala wrapper around the [Torch](https://github.com/torch/torch7) libraries. I'm using [Swig](http://www.swig.org/) to build the glue layer. It allows me to create tensors off-heap, which I can only free by explicitly calling a static method of the library. However, I want to use the tensors in an imperative way, without having to worry about releasing the memory, much like any ordinary object in Java.

The only way I can think of doing this is to (mis-)use the JVM's garbage collector in the following way:

A 'memory manager' keeps track of the amount of off-heap memory consumed, and when a threshold is reached, it calls `System.gc()`.

```
object MemoryManager {    
  val Threshold: Long = 2L * 1024L * 1024L * 1024L // 2 GB
  val FloatSize = 4
  private val hiMemMark = new AtomicLong(0)

  def dec(size: Long): Long = hiMemMark.addAndGet(-size * FloatSize)
  def inc(size: Long): Long = hiMemMark.addAndGet(size * FloatSize)

  def memCheck(size: Long): Unit = {
    val level = inc(size)
    if (level > Threshold) {
      System.gc()
    }
  }
}
```

The tensors themselves are wrapped in a class, with a finalize method, that frees the off-heap memory, like so:

```
class Tensor private (val payload: SWIGTYPE_p_THFloatTensor) {
  def numel: Int = TH.THFloatTensor_numel(payload)

  override def finalize(): Unit = {
    val memSize = MemoryManager.dec(numel)
    TH.THFloatTensor_free(payload)
  }    
}
```

Tensor creation is done by a factory method, that notifies the memory manager. For example, to create a Tensor of zeros:

```
object Tensor {
  def zeros(shape: List[Int]): Tensor = {
      MemoryManager.memCheck(shape.product)
      val storage = ... // boilerplate
      val t = TH.THFloatTensor_new
      TH.THFloatTensor_zeros(t, storage)
      new Tensor(t)
  }
}
```

I realize this is a naive approach, but can I get away with this? It seems to work fine, also when running in parallel (which generates lots of superfluous calls to `System.gc()` but otherwise nothing)
Or can you think of a better solution?

Thank you.

Comment: This could work fine.  What I do is something like using direct ByteBuffer which does similar.

Comment: @PeterLawrey this is interesting, but I cannot find how they do this in the JVM code, or in the docs. Could you provide a link? Thank you.

Comment: I suggest reading the source. You can click on it in your IDE or use http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/DirectByteBuffer.java?av=f

Comment: If you look at it's parents you find http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/nio/Buffer.java#Buffer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a more deterministic option - explicitly managed regions of memory

So, roughly if we had a class like this:

```
class Region private () {
  private val registered = ArrayBuffer.empty[() => Unit]
  def register(finalizer: () => Unit): Unit = registered += finalizer
  def releaseAll(): Unit = {
    registered.foreach(f => f()) // todo - will leak if f() throws
  }
}
```

We could have a method implementing so-called "Loan pattern" that gives us a fresh region and then handles the deallocation

```
object Region {
  def run[A](f: Region => A): A = {
    val r = new Region
    try f(r) finally r.releaseAll()
  }
}
```

Then something that requires manual deallocation could be described as taking an implicit `Region`:

```
class Leakable(i: Int)(implicit r: Region) {
  // Class body is constructor body, so you can register finalizers
  r.register(() => println(s"Deallocated foo $i"))

  def foo() = println(s"Foo: $i")
}
```

Which you would be able to use in a fairly boilerplate-free way:

```
Region.run { implicit r =>
  val a = new Leakable(1)
  val b = new Leakable(2)
  b.foo()
  a.foo()
}
```

This code produces the following output:

```
Foo: 2
Foo: 1
Deallocated foo 1
Deallocated foo 2
```

Such approach is limiting a little bit (if you try to assign a `Leakable` to a variable outside the closure passed in `run`, its scope will not be promoted), but will be faster and guaranteed to work even if calls to `System.gc` are disabled.

Comment: Thanks Oleg, I'll let this sink in for a while.

Comment: I think this is a very elegant solution. Thank you.